# Disable links from auto created drop-down menu js

Tags: javascript, html, css, resizable

Fixed:

So I got this piece of javascript that will show an drop-down menu when the browser is small enough (done with some @media). The menu is created automatically based on the menu for bigger screen sizes.  Now my issue is that it also creates links from "Something1" and "Something2".

I would like these to be shown but disables, so not clickable.

FIX: The only thing what had to be added so that it didn't linked "Something1/2" to non-exsisting pages was :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-liquidslider-ref="main-slider">Actual Link</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)">Something1</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" data-liquidslider-ref="main-slider">Actual Link</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-liquidslider-ref="main-slider">Actual Link</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Something2</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" data-liquidslider-ref="main-slider">Actual Link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-liquidslider-ref="main-slider">Actual Link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-liquidslider-ref="main-slider">Actual Link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-liquidslider-ref="main-slider">Actual Link</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact" data-liquidslider-ref="main-slider">Actual Link</a>

                </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

JS

```
// Create the dropdown base
$("<select />").appendTo("nav");

// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
    "selected": "selected",
        "value": "",
        "text": "Go to..."
}).appendTo("nav select");

// Populate dropdown with menu items
$("nav a").each(function () {
    var el = $(this);
    $("<option />", {
        "value": el.attr("href"),
            "text": el.text()
    }).appendTo("nav select");
});

$("nav select").change(function () {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is your issue exactly? Those links are not clickable in your jsFiddle

Comment: True. In the css they form a horizontal bar. when hovering on those (something1/2) the drop down appears. Now with the javascript, it also creates links from those two. Is there a way to make an exception in the javascript ? So that i can give the values of those i don't want to be clickable.

Note that the javascript is only implented when the screen size gets small enough. The actual horizontal menu dissapears and the drop down which the js makes, appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to create a blank link would be as followed,

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```

I'm not sure which is the best option but I recently started to use the second option. When you use the first option it will add the `#` symbol to the end of your url which can mess up active nav links.